# php not displaying errors at all

Tags: php

PHP 7.2

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo 'err: '.ini_get('display_errors').'<br>';

// should display error
echo $test;
```

## output

```
err: 1
```

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried it with something that produces an error instead of a notice?

Comment: Dunno what to say... my php 7.2 server (copy pasted that code to a blank script), tosses a `Notice`. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if display_errors is off by checking the php.ini file. This is located at various different places depending on your operating system or distribution, but is commonly at /etc/php.ini or similar. Open up the file and look for "display_errors" and you'll find something along these lines:

display_errors = Off - make this On

Use ini_get or get_cfg_var
Another way to check the status of the display_errors configuration variable is with the ini_get or get_cfg_var functions as shown in the following example:

echo (integer)ini_get('display_errors')

Comment: I'm already checking it by doing `echo 'err: '.ini_get('display_errors').'<br>';` and it is on.. but no errors are displayed